# Finding maximal ideals and Krull dimension

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> I have difficulties in finding the maximal ideals and compute the dimension of a quotient ring $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(x^2-y^2,z^2x-z^2y)$.

Here $(x^2-y^2,z^2x-z^2y)$ is a product of $(x+y,z^2)$ and $(x-y)$. But they are not coprime, so the product is not the intersection. And this ideal is not prime. Then I don't know how to deal with it. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: So is the second generator $z^2x-z^2y$? Because of your product decomposition....This really makes a big impact on the dimension: The ring $\mathbb C[x,y,z]/(x^2-y^2,z^2x-zy^2)$ is one-dimensional. The ring $\mathbb C[x,y,z]/(x^2-y^2,z^2x-z^2y)$ is two-dimensional.

Comment: Yeah, I have edited it. I am really sorry for the typo.

Comment: How to find minimal primes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(x-y)$ is a prime of height $1$, which contains $(x^2-y^2,z^2x-z^2y)$, so your ring has dimension at least two, since we have a chain $(x-y) \subset (x-y,z) \subset (x,y,z)$.

On the other hand it has dimension at most two, since it is a non-trivial quotient of the $3$-dimensional polynomial ring.

For the maximal ideals you should use $V(IJ) = V(I) \cup V(J)$. You can also make use of the Nullstellensatz: The maximal ideals, that contain a given ideal, correspond to the solutions of the system of equations given by the generators of the ideal.

Comment: Why it has dimension at most two? It is a non-trivial quotient. Then why the dimension of it is strictly smaller than the polynomial ring? Thank you!

Comment: Let $A$ be an integral domain and $A/I$ a non-trivial quotient. If you have a chain of primes in $A/I$, you can always add the zero-ideal at the bottom of this chain to get a longer chain in $A$. Hence the dimension of $A/I$ is strictly smaller.

More generally if $A$ is a noetherian ring of finite krull dimension and $I$ an ideal, which contains a non-zero divisor, then $A/I$ has strictly smaller dimension.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!